# How do I make a permanent variable out of AngularJS form input?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am having a lot of trouble with this problem, and your help is much appreciated.

Here is my html:

```
<form ng-submit="doLogin()" name="student">
      <div class="list">
          <ion-radio ng-model="grade" ng-value="0">Kindergarten</ion-radio>
          <ion-radio ng-model="grade" ng-value="1">1st Grade</ion-radio>
          <ion-radio ng-model="grade" ng-value="2">2nd Grade</ion-radio>
          <ion-radio ng-model="grade" ng-value="3">3rd Grade</ion-radio>
          <ion-radio ng-model="grade" ng-value="4">4th Grade</ion-radio>
          <ion-radio ng-model="grade" ng-value="5">5th Grade</ion-radio>
          <ion-radio ng-model="grade" ng-value="6">6th Grade</ion-radio>
          <ion-radio ng-model="grade" ng-value="7">7th Grade</ion-radio>
          <ion-radio ng-model="grade" ng-value="8">8th Grade</ion-radio>
          <ion-radio ng-model="grade" ng-value="9">9th Grade</ion-radio>
          <ion-radio ng-model="grade" ng-value="10">10th Grade</ion-radio>
          <ion-radio ng-model="grade" ng-value="11">11th Grade</ion-radio>
          <ion-radio ng-model="grade" ng-value="12">12th Grade</ion-radio>


        <label class="item">
          <button class="button button-block button-positive" type="submit">Log in</button>
        </label>
      </div>
</form>
```

And my controllers.js:

```
    angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $localstorage) {
  // Form data for the login modal
  $scope.loginData = {};

  // Create the login modal that we will use later
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/setgrade.html', {
    scope: $scope
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });
  $scope.modalOpen = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
  };
    var grade = $localstorage.getObject('grade');
    if(grade === undefined){
        doLogin();
    };

  // Perform the login action when the user submits the login form
  $scope.doLogin = function($scope, $localstorage) {
    console.log('Doing login', $scope.loginData);
    localStorage['grade'] = $scope.student)
  };
})
```

So, to summarize, is there a way for me to pull the value of the radio list, make it a locally stored variable, and recall that locally stored variable in a function or if/else statement (and by locally stored variable, I mean stored on the device until the app is deleted)? I would also like to open the modal with the form if the locally stored variable is undefined, and leave it closed if it is not.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're just looking for "local storage". They describe it here -http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/localstorage/,  but you can also use a module like angular-local-storage https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage.

Comment: That did not work for me @Dylan

Comment: Could you please fully answer my question? I have little idea what I am doing in this case. Thank you @Dylan !

Comment: Why doesn't local storage work?

Comment: Oh wait, there may be a logic error here: `if grade(...) doLogin()`. It should probably be `$scope.doLogin($scope, $localstorage)`.

Comment: Also, this line `localStorage['grade'] = $scope.student)` should probably be `$localstorage.setObject('grade', $scope.student);`

Comment: What would the finished code look like? @AustinMullins

Comment: I've got [an example working on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FS9gC0JK4PV1jujBMJDG?p=preview). The problem is I don't know how well it correlates with what you're seeing on a mobile device.

Comment: Where would ionic.utils go directory-wise? @AustinMullins

Comment: Wherever you want. Why?

Comment: I didn't see the <script> tag importing it. Also, the modal won't show up, and I am getting the `Access to restricted URI denied` error. @AustinMullins

Comment: It was this line: `<script src="ionic.utils.js"></script>`. What was supposed to make the modal show?

Comment: The `if` function that checked if the variable was undefined. @AustinMullins

Comment: `Access to restricted URI denied` is the error that is being returned, and the modal doesn't show up... Any suggestions? @AustinMullins

Comment: @AustinMullins I actually had the template source wrong. Thank you so much for all your help.

Comment: It is now returning an error that `$scope.modal` is undefined... @AustinMullins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the changes you need are here:

```
// Inside controller definition
  var grade = $localstorage.getObject('grade');
  if(grade === undefined){
      $scope.doLogin(); // Was doLogin()
  }

  // Perform the login action when the user submits the login form
  $scope.doLogin = function() {
    console.log('Doing login', $scope.loginData);
    $localstorage.setObject('grade', $scope.grade); // Was localStorage['grade'] = $scope.grade); // With extra closing paren
  };
})
```

This is assuming you have a working `$localstorage` service, an example of which is provided [by the Ionic folks here](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/localstorage/). Of course, this needs to be declared as a dependency of your app like so:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ionic', 'ionic.utils'])
```

Here, it is assumed that the `$localstorage` service is defined inside `iconic.utils`. It could be somewhere else, if desired.

I got it working in Chrome on a desktop [in this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FS9gC0JK4PV1jujBMJDG?p=preview), but I don't know for sure whether that translates to your app.

I later noticed the part of your question where you stated you wanted to show the modal as part of the `doLogin` function. I looked up the [docs on Ionic modal](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/making-modals/) and played around on [a separate Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FKT2O4TNd7VGag1CkrlF?p=preview) for a while and eventually landed on what I think you were going for.

The full controller is here:

```
 angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ionic', 'ionic.utils'])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $localstorage) {
  $scope.grade = $scope.storedGrade = $localstorage.get('grade');
  $scope.loginData = { name: "", grade:  $scope.grade};

  $scope.modalOpen = function() {
    console.log("Modal Opening");
    $scope.loginData.grade = $scope.grade;
    $scope.modal.show();
  };

  $scope.modalClose = function() {
    $scope.grade = $scope.loginData.grade;
    $scope.modal.hide();
    console.log("Modal Closed");
    $localstorage.set('grade', $scope.grade);
    $scope.storedGrade = $localstorage.get('grade');
  };

  // Perform the login action when the user submits the login form
  $scope.doLogin = function() {
    console.log('Doing login', $scope.loginData.name);
    $scope.modalOpen();
  };

  // Create the login modal that we will use later
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('setgrade.html', {
    scope: $scope
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
    if(typeof $scope.grade === "undefined"){
      $scope.doLogin();
    }
  });
});
```

I was playing around with the order of definitions inside the controller because of some `unexpected token undefined` errors Ionic was throwing. Basically, if the data you're storing is simple (a single string or a number), you should use `$localstorage.get` and `$localstorage.set` instead of `getObject` and `setObject`. I call `modalOpen` in the `doLogin` function and then handle the inputs from the modal in the `modalClose` function.

Since you were getting cross-site security errors on your end, I followed the example in the Ionic modal documentation and embedded the modal template in a script tag on the main HTML page.